# Json.net can't serialize classes that derive from Monobehaviour

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I'm trying to serialize a save file but Json.net can't seem to serialize classes that derive from Monobehaviour. The error it gives me is as follows

> NotSupportedException: rigidbody property has been deprecated

There are no rigidbodies used in this project anywhere, so this error is very confusing to me. It might be worth noting that I'm using an old version of Json.net(3.5.8) as this is the latest version that supports the projects framework(3.5)

The save file itself does not derive from Monobehaviour, but inside of it are properties that do. This causes the error to apear.

This is the code I'm using to test the serialization, as you can see it should serialize the save, print out the result, desrialize it and then print it out again.

```
 var test1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SaveManager.currentSave, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
            });

            Debug.Log(test1);

            var test2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Save>(test1);

            Debug.Log(test2);
```

**Save class**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Com.BlewScreen.Woongame
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Save
    {
        private bool initialSave = true;

        private string saveName;

        //Player var
        private House house;
        private string districtHouseName;
        private House wantsToMove;
        private string districtWantsToMoveToName;

        [System.NonSerialized]
        public District houseDistrict;
        [System.NonSerialized]
        public District wantsToMoveToDistrict;

        private int income;
        private int health;
        private int balance;
        private int livingpleasure;
        private int regtime;
        private bool disabled;
        private bool hasPartner;
        private int kids;
        private int livingSituationCount;

        //Housing market var
        private DistrictStats a;    //Tom: Change this to "DistrictStatsA" etc. instead of just a, b, c, d, e
        private DistrictStats b;
        private DistrictStats c;
        private DistrictStats d;
        private DistrictStats e;

        private string characterIndexes;

        public string CharacterIndexes { get; set; }

        public string characterSkinTone;

        public string CharacterSkinTone { get; set; }

        public House House
        {
            get{ return house; }
            set{ house = value; }
        }
        public House WantsToMove
        {
            get{ return wantsToMove; }
            set{ wantsToMove = value; }
        }      
        public int Income
        {
            get { return income; }
            set{ income = value; }
        }
        public int Health
        {
            get{ return health; }
            set{ health = value; }
        }
        public int Balance
        {
            get{ return balance; }
            set{ balance = value;}
        }
        public int Livingpleasure
        {
            get{ return livingpleasure;}
            set{ livingpleasure = value;}
        }
        public int Regtime
        {
            get{ return regtime;}
            set{ regtime = value;}
        }
        public bool Disabled
        {
            get{ return disabled;}
            set{ disabled = value;}
        }
        public bool HasPartner
        {
            get{ return hasPartner;}
            set{ hasPartner = value;}
        }
        public int Kids
        {
            get{ return kids;}
            set{ kids = value;}
        }
        public DistrictStats A
        {
            get{ return a;}
            set{ a = value;}
        }
        public DistrictStats B
        {
            get{ return b; }
            set{ b = value;}
        }
        public DistrictStats C
        {
            get{ return c;}
            set { c = value;}
        }
        public DistrictStats D
        {
            get{ return d;}
            set{ d = value;}
        }
        public DistrictStats E
        {
            get{ return e;}
            set{ e = value; }
        }
        public string DistrictHouseName
        {
            get{ return districtHouseName;}
            set{ districtHouseName = value; }
        }
        public string DistrictWantsToMoveToName
        {
            get{ return districtWantsToMoveToName;}
            set{ districtWantsToMoveToName = value; }
        }
        public bool InitialSave
        {
            get{ return initialSave; }
            set{ initialSave = value;}
        }
        public int LivingSituationCount
        {
            get{ return livingSituationCount;}
            set{ livingSituationCount = value; }
        }
        public string SaveName
        {
            get{ return saveName; }
            set{ saveName = value; }
        }

        public Save()
        {
            InitialSave = true;
        }
        public Save(string saveName, House house, House wantsToMove, 
                    int income, int health, int balance, int livingpleasure, 
                    int regtime, bool disabled, bool hasPartner, int kids, 
                    int livingSituationCount, DistrictStats a, DistrictStats b, 
                    DistrictStats c, DistrictStats d, DistrictStats e, string characterIndexes, string characterSkinTone)
        {
            initialSave = false;
            DistrictHouseName = house.District.DistrictName;

            if(wantsToMove != null)
            {
                DistrictWantsToMoveToName = wantsToMove.District.DistrictName;

            }

            this.saveName = saveName;
            this.House = house;
            this.WantsToMove = wantsToMove;
            this.Income = income;
            this.Health = health;
            this.Balance = balance;
            this.Livingpleasure = livingpleasure;
            this.Regtime = regtime;
            this.Disabled = disabled;
            this.HasPartner = hasPartner;
            this.Kids = kids;
            this.LivingSituationCount = livingSituationCount;
            A = a;
            B = b;
            C = c;
            D = d;
            E = e;
            this.CharacterIndexes = characterIndexes;
            this.CharacterSkinTone = characterSkinTone;

        }
    }
}
```

**Full error stack**

> NotSupportedException: rigidbody property has been deprecated
>   UnityEngine.GameObject.get_rigidbody () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/GameObject.deprecated.cs:23)
>   (wrapper dynamic-method) UnityEngine.GameObject.Getrigidbody (object) 
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue (object) 
>   Rethrow as JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'rigidbody' on 'UnityEngine.GameObject'.
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue (System.Object target)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, System.Object value, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract collectionValueContract)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity 5 GameObject serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786488/unity-5-gameobject-serialization)

Comment: The objects in that the save includes are derived from GameObject? This has nothing to do with Json.Net rather with deprecated unity features.

Comment: @KristófTóth The property house for example has a property called disctrict which derives from Monobehaviour and has GameObject elements whitin it.

Comment: I've come across the Unity 5 GameObject serialization post but the thing is there are no rigidbodies used in this project so there are no rigidbody calls either.

Comment: Thank that is the problem, since you are trying to serialize the whole container object, it will reach the deprecated properties eventually and throw an exception because of the deprecated features. Check the thread mentioned above, it will provide you with a solution

Comment: The post mentioned above only says not to call rigid body in the old way however I'm not using any rigidbodies @KristófTóth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot serialize a MonoBehaviour or any Unity Component.

This error is most likely caused by Json.net trying to get the .rigidbody property value and as it is deprecated this is thrown.

So if this error was avoided the process would still fail. Remove any Monobehaviours from your Save or create a new class to contain the data you want saved.

Comment: Correct. Just serialise what you need, not the whole shooting match.

Comment: so what how would one go about serializing such data?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

- Add `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` attribute to the component class and add `[JsonProperty]` attribute to the property/field.
- Write a [Custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for each component.

These options do not suit my use case since I have multiple components and properties to be serialized. I also want to include the `name` property from `UnityEngine.Object`, but we can't add the attribute to the class.

What I did was override the `CreateProperties` method in my [ContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm).

```
protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
    // Only filter class that is derived from MonoBehaviour
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MonoBehaviour)))
    {
        // Keep name property OR properties derived from MonoBehaviour
        properties = properties.Where(x => x.PropertyName.Equals("name") || x.DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MonoBehaviour))).ToList();
    }
    return properties;
}
```